# node.js mongodb query was working fine until replica set setup and result is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I have followed mongo documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/ to setup replica set (3 instances only) in my local windows machine. I tested the followings and works fine:

1. inserted data and connect to PRIMARY using robomongo and can see the data
2. stop PRIMARY and 1 of SECONDARY take over as PRIMARY and all the data are there.
3. brought up the the one I just stopped and it is SECONDARY now.

My problems:

1. when use robomongo to connect to any of SECONDARY I can't see the data although it is there.
2. my query code below always return null although there is data in mongodb

the connection string is (no authentication needed)

**mongodb://mark2:27017,mark2:27018,mark2:27019/mydb?w=0&readPreference=secondary&replSet=rs0**

I **rs.status()** and it shows all 3 nodes active.

```
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 3,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "mark2:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "mark2:27018"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "mark2:27019"
                }
        ]
}
```

**The query is a simple query**

```
db.collection("user").findOne({email:"yummy@gmail.com"}, function(err, result) {

       if(result) { // result always null which it wasn't before setting up replica set


       } else {


       }

});
```

Appreciate any advice please. Thanks !

Cheerio,
Mark Thien

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry my terrible fault. I put in the world database name.